# iron-scroll-threshold on an iron-page

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm having troubles using `iron-scroll-threshold` along with an `iron-page` which shares the same host as other pages.

My application UI has `paper-tabs` on top. Pages are loaded lazily as the tabs change. One of the pages contain large amount of AJAX data from an endpoint so I have to implement scroll pagination on it.

My problem is, I'm trying to get `iron-scroll-threshold` to fire in that particular page (which shares same dom scroll as other pages). I know I can consider using `iron-list` with an explicit height for the page, but I don't want to since it breaks my app's UX by adding automatically two `overflow`.

My question is, how do I fire `on-lower-threshold` whenever I reach the bottom of a particular `iron-page`? I tried using it with `dom-repeat` by following.

```
    <iron-scroll-threshold
          lower-threshold="100"
          on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData"
          scroll-target="itemlist"
          >
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]" as="list" id="itemlist">
        <a href="[[list.id]]">
          <p>[[list.name]]</p>
        </a>
      </template>
    </iron-scroll-threshold>
```

Another problem I face is it automatically fires the event before ajax call is completed. After that, even if the dom has loaded, it never fired again.

You can ask me more specific questions if you're not clear. Happy new year folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<iron-scroll-threshold>.scrollTarget` setting should be removed because the `<iron-scroll-threshold>` itself is the scroll target in this case.

You could create a custom page element that includes the `<iron-scroll-threshold>` as the item container. Make sure to set its height to `100%`.

```
<dom-module id="x-page">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      iron-scroll-threshold {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
    <iron-scroll-threshold lower-threshold="100"
                           on-lower-threshold="_loadMoreData">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <div>[[index]]: [[item]]</div>
      </template>
    </iron-scroll-threshold>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NdyNGX?editors=1010)